# Change styles to toggled divs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

Im using filtered divs and I want to change the flex-direction of each section only when that specific section is toggled, then go back to original styles when going back to "Show all"

Here is the link for the filtered divs
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_filter_elements

Comment: Have you tried anything that is not on w3School ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, in future you would be well served to show what attempts you have made to solve the problem instead of just providing a link to W3Schools (there are much better resources out there) . For example you mention flex-direction, yet your example doesn't even involve flex. At the minimum you should have reworked the W3Schools version to use flex and attempt to solve the direction switch yourself. The easier you make  it for us to help you the more help (and less downvotes) you will get.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what you meant by "flexible steering", would it be to replace the phrase "Show all" with the active section? This can be done with jquery, but you would have to replace the element that houses the text.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="all">Show all</button>
<button type="button" id="cars">cars</button>
<script>
$("#cars").on("click", function(){
    $("#all").text('Cars');
});
$("#all").on("click", function(){
    $("#all").text('Show All');
});
</script>
```

**Alternative without jquery**

```html
<button id="all">Show All</button>
<button id="cars" onclick="cars()">Cars</button>

<script>
function cars() {
    document.getElementById("all").innerHTML = "Cars";
}
</script>
```

**Alternative to build the tab without so much javascript and css**

- **Bootstrap Collapse**: You can use Bootstrap Colapse which already has a structure ready and you would only have to organize the HTML with the divs as per the documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/
- **Javascript behavior**: Like the previous one, this is a tabbed browsing API, which is identical to the code you are using, with the difference that here you would be using the Bootstrap structure and will not require many modifications, you should note the similarity between this and the previous one, in fact what changes is only the usability, the situations in which you will use one or the other, but the purpose is the same, both seek to hide elements.
  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#javascript-behavior

Comment: jQuery is REALLY not needed here

Comment: It depends on what he intends to do, as I understand it, he wants the text "show everything" to be replaced by the text of the button that the user clicks, that is, the button would change its position and become the first, what I suggested was just change the text instead of changing the position of the button, it seems to me that he does not want to change the active button, but rather to change the position.

Comment: Can still be easily done without jQuery (and I love jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

The W3 Schools code is not very good. It can be improved greatly but the use of [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes), [proper event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and  [event bubbling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events)

All we need to to to get your "flex switch" happening is add/remove a class to the ".container" to indicate if filtered or not

```js
var container = document.querySelector(".container");

//Add an event listener to the div containing the buttons
document.getElementById("myBtnContainer").addEventListener("click", function(event) {

  //remove active class from previous active button
  this.querySelector(".active").classList.remove("active");
  //add active class to clicked item
  event.target.classList.add("active");

  //Add filitered to ".container" if "All" clicked, remove otherwise
  container.classList.toggle("filtered", event.target.dataset.target !== "all")
  
  //Display chosen elements
  var elements = container.querySelectorAll(".filterDiv");
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    //Long version of below
    //var categoryArray = elements[i].dataset.category.split(",");
    //var hasTargetCategory = categoryArray.includes(event.target.dataset.target);
    //elements[i].classList.toggle("show",hasTargetCategory);

    elements[i].classList.toggle("show", elements[i].dataset.category.split(",").includes(event.target.dataset.target));
  }
})
```

```css
.filterDiv {
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2px;
  flex: none;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

/* Style the buttons */

.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.btn.active {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}


/*Class to change flex direction*/
.filtered {
  flex-direction: column;
}


/*Hide elements without the show class*/
.filtered>.filterDiv:not(.show) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="myBtnContainer">
  <button class="btn active" data-target="all"> Show all</button>
  <button class="btn" data-target="cars"> Cars</button>
  <button class="btn" data-target="animals"> Animals</button>
  <button class="btn" data-target="fruits"> Fruits</button>
  <button class="btn" data-target="colors"> Colors</button>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="filterDiv" data-category="cars">BMW</div>
  <div class="filterDiv" data-category="colors,fruits">Orange</div>
  <div class="filterDiv" data-category="cars">Volvo</div>
  <div class="filterDiv" data-category="colors">Red</div>
  <div class="filterDiv" data-category="cars,animals">Mustang</div>
  <div class="filterDiv" data-category="colors">Blue</div>
  <div class="filterDiv" data-category="animals">Cat</div>
  <div class="filterDiv" data-category="animals">Dog</div>
  <div class="filterDiv" data-category="fruits">Melon</div>
  <div class="filterDiv" data-category="fruits,animals">Kiwi</div>
  <div class="filterDiv" data-category="fruits">Banana</div>
  <div class="filterDiv" data-category="fruits">Lemon</div>
  <div class="filterDiv" data-category="animals">Cow</div>
</div>
```